# Apache Velocity Round up to multiple

Tags: apache, velocity

There doesn't seem to be a round function in Apache. I want to evaluate a value and if its not a multiple of 8, round it up to the nearest multiple

```
value=16 #do nothing
Value = 1 #round up to 8
value = 10 # round up to 16
value = 20 #round up to 24
value = 29 #round up to 32
```

etc

I can use modulus to evaluate if the value is a multiple but the math functions are very limited after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do:

```
#set($value = ($value + 7) / 8 * 8)
```